# i18n Padrino 0.12.2 with Mongoid 3.0.23 + Auto Locale

Tags: ruby, internationalization, mongoid, padrino

Repository: https://github.com/bcsantos/translate

Live instance: http://ta-translate.herokuapp.com/

Live instance admin: http://ta-translate.herokuapp.com/admin (email: foo@bar.com pwd: foobar)

---

**Note**

<strike>as explained below, at the moment the only way I can change locale in admin is with</strike>

```
set :locales, []
```

and refreshing both website front-end and admin. this doesn't seem to work on the live instance.

```
I18n.default_locale = :pt_br
```

in admin/app.rb is the only way I could find until now to set locale in admin, whereas

```
I18n.locale = :pt_br
```

doesn't work.

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/admin/app.rb

---

*#boot.rb*

```
Padrino.before_load do
  I18n.locale = :en
end

require 'padrino-contrib/auto_locale'
```

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/config/boot.rb

*#app.rb*

```
set :locales, [:en, :pt_br]
```

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/app/app.rb

---

**Problem A**

```
switch_to_lang(:lang)
```

isn't working in this context

```
%li.divider
%li
  =link_to "EN", switch_to_lang(:en)
%li.divider
%li
  =link_to "PT", switch_to_lang(:pt_br)
```

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/app/views/partials/_menu.haml

as it stands, the only ways i can find to set locale are

```
set :locales, [:en, :pt_br] # in front-end

I18n.default_locale = :pt_br # in admin
```

---

**Problem B**

is the a way to include all paths under a certain route?

the only urls that are being localized are generated by

```
get :image, with: [:id, :name] do
  # params[:splat] still contains whatever is entered at the end
  amenity = Amenity.find(params[:id])
  content_type amenity.picture.content_type      
  #response.headers['Content-Length'] = amenity.picture.length
  response.write(amenity.picture.read)
  response.finish
end
```

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/app/controllers/amenities.rb

which should generate http://tourapart.herokuapp.com/artworks/image/53ac2904895e9fa4f4000018/picture.jpg/picture
but under the current branch in localhost gets something like

```
/amenities/image/5391dbdef2c796e026000001/picture.jpg?lang=en
```

therefore not found. is there a way to

```
set :locale_exclusive_paths, ['/amenities/image/']
```

to include all routes under that one? regex

```
set :locale_exclusive_paths, ['/\/amenities\/image\/*/']
```

isn't working.

---

**Problem C, ...**

Pages are gone, not found, and renaming the templates to include locale in filename has done nothing until this point, locale data works for links but not model attributes:

```
%a= link_to "#{t "links.amenities"}".upcase!, '/amenities'
```

works, but:

```
class Amenity
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps # adds created_at and updated_at fields

  # field <name>, :type => <type>, :default => <value>

  field :name, localize: true, :type => String
  field :description, localize: true, :type => String
  field :category, localize: true, :type => String
  field :price, localize: true, :type => Integer
  field :phone, :type => String

  mount_uploader :picture, Uploader

  field :featured, :type => Boolean

  # You can define indexes on documents using the index macro:
  # index :field <, :unique => true>

  # You can create a composite key in mongoid to replace the default id using the key macro:
  # key :field <, :another_field, :one_more ....>
end
```

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/app/models/amenity.rb

**does** change attribute names in admin, with this yml:

```
pt_br:
  models:
    amenity: 
      name: Complemento
      attributes:
        created_at: Criado em
        updated_at: Actualizado em
        name: Nome
        description: Descrição
        category: Categoria
        price: Preço
        phone: Telefone
        medium: Meio
        featured: Destacado
        picture: Imagem
```

but **doesn't** translate model names themselves

https://github.com/bcsantos/translate/blob/master/app/locale/models/amenity/pt_br.yml

finally,

```
url('path')
```

not generating localized urls, should it not?

In short,

- only the homepage is showing in front-end;
- the images route is broken;
- admin **does** translate user onterface and model attribute names but **doesn't** translate model names, in menu;
- admin does however correctly show the fields for each locale, when changed via set :locales [] (in development mode only), and data is persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this. One step at a time.

#### Use the *right* gem versions

You should be using the `HEAD` padrino-contrib. From the latest published stable (v0.1.13) until the `master`, they seem to have fixed lots of bugs regarding `auto_locale`.

```
# Gemfile
gem "padrino-contrib", github: "padrino/padrino-contrib"
```

#### Setting locales

Forget about `default_locale`. It was used in older versions. Setting `I18n.locale=` in the `before_load` is the right way of doing it.

Notwithstanding, when using `auto_locale`, this setting gets overridden by the [first locale](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-contrib/blob/master/lib/padrino-contrib/auto_locale.rb#L51) set in the `locales` variable. And it is not set at all, it [defaults](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-contrib/blob/master/lib/padrino-contrib/auto_locale.rb#L51) to `en`.

That said, for the sake of consistency, I'd set `I18n.locale=` to the same value of the first element of the `locales` array. In case it is used by other libraries, e.g. generators.

#### Problem A

With the above set, `switch_to_lang` works as expected. All it does is append the passed `lang` argument to the `request.path_info`, thus generating:

```
# GET /admin
switch_to_lang(:en) # => /admin/en
```

#### Problem B

Yes, you can use regular expressions in the `locale_exclusive_paths`, but be aware that quoting a regular expression transforms it into a `String`. And padrino [checks the type](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-contrib/blob/master/lib/padrino-contrib/auto_locale.rb#L93) of the input to decide what to exclude.

```
> "/foo/".is_a?(Regexp) # => false
> "/foo/".is_a?(String) # => true
> /foo/.is_a?(Regexp)   # => true
> /foo/.is_a?(String)   # => false
```

#### Problem C

I've never used `padrino-admin`, so I can't help much on that. But have you tried the [model_translate](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/master/padrino-admin/lib/padrino-admin/helpers/view_helpers.rb#L80) (or mt) view helper?

Finally, `url` generates localized urls, but only for mapped routes, e.g.

```
# GET /en
# Suppose there is in your controller the following definition
# get :index { ... }
url("/") # => /
url(:index) # => /en
```

I really hope that helps. Padrino seems an interesting project, but there are still room for improvements. Should your project become more complex, i.e. more models, controllers, etc. you might consider switching it to rails.

Best!

Comment: mostly everything sorted, i'm still having a couple of issues but these are mostly Padrino specific. marking this as the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: Not in time for the bounty but, I'm glad I could help anyway. Cheers!

Comment: 1 quick question: suppose you didn't use autolocale, how would you set up a link to change locale? i don't really need autolocale in padrino admin, and it seems to mess up routes, just need a way of providing links to change locale, so users can insert content for each language.

yep, shame about the bounty going to waste.